# Css Icon Does Not Work After Host Upload

Tags: asp.net, css, image

[image]

I use a template for my web project and in asp.net. In localhost my icons seen clearly like top of picture but when i upload it to host it seen like below the correct one. When i look css codes of template i saw like this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.1.0');
src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.1.0') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.1.0') format('woff'),url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.1.0') format('truetype'),url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular?v=3.1.0') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
font-family: FontAwesome;
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
text-decoration: inherit;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
*margin-right: .3em;
}

[class^="icon-"]:before, [class*=" icon-"]:before {
    text-decoration: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    speak: none;
}

.icon-large:before {
vertical-align: -10%;
font-size: 1.3333333333333333em;
}

a [class^="icon-"], a [class*=" icon-"], a [class^="icon-"]:before, a [class*=" icon-"]:before {
display: inline;
}

[class^="icon-"].icon-fixed-width, [class*=" icon-"].icon-fixed-width {
display: inline-block;
width: 1.2857142857142858em;
text-align: center;
}

[class^="icon-"].icon-fixed-width.icon-large, [class*=" icon-"].icon-fixed-width.icon-large {
    width: 1.5714285714285714em;
}

ul.icons-ul {
list-style-type: none;
text-indent: -0.7142857142857143em;
margin-left: 2.142857142857143em;
}

ul.icons-ul > li .icon-li {
    width: .7142857142857143em;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

[class^="icon-"].hide, [class*=" icon-"].hide {
display: none;
}

.icon-muted {
color: #eee;
}


.icon-glass:before {
content: "\f000";
}
```

I am not good at css. What is that and how can i solve this?

Comment: Did you upload the font as-well?

Comment: Yes i did upload.

Edit: Upss. When i publish my project in Visual Studio, it doesn't put font folder in publish directory. I passed it.

Comment: It's difficult to see what the problem is without access to your webhost.  Is the font in the correct map? Exactly in the same path as you specified? I mean this line: ../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.1.0

Comment: I shall answer this question, accept it, then it won't show up as unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you also upload the font to the webhost, and link it correctly according to this line: `../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.1.0`